# Remove blank line(s) before or after read()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to remove the blank line(s) in a file before sending it to parse() in the following code:

```
import robotexclusionrulesparser as rerp
p = rerp.RobotExclusionRulesParser()

with open('robots.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

p.parse(s)

print(p)
```

I tried this without success:

```
import re
import robotexclusionrulesparser as rerp
p = rerp.RobotExclusionRulesParser()

list = []
with open('robots.txt') as f:
    s = f.read() 
    if not re.match(r'^\s*$', s):
        list.append(s)
p.parse(list)

print(p)
```

Which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    p.parse(list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotexclusionrulesparser.py", line 530, in parse
    s = s.decode("iso-8859-1")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

For debug purpose, example of content of robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove those blank lines?

Comment: Blank lines in the robots.txt stop the former conditions... So the rules aren't respected. Google doesn't respect the RFC, unlike the library robotexclusionrulesparser which is very good at respecting the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is what you want, but instead of `match`, use `sub`:

```
s = f.read()
s = re.sub(r'\n+', '\\n', s)
```

[Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/31v3zc/1/)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve the problem:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    p.parse(list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotexclusionrulesparser.py", line 530, in parse
    s = s.decode("iso-8859-1")
AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Tested with: 
with open('robots.txt') as f:
    s = f.read() 
    s = re.sub(r'\n+', '\\n', s)

p.parse(list)
print(p)

Comment: @Quentin Do you need to supply the `p.parse` function with a list or a string?

Comment: It requires a string. Following your answer, I converted the list into a string with \n at the end of the lines and it works. Here is the magic: "s = '\n'.join(lst)". Thx

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
import re
lst = []
with open('robots.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
            lst.append(line.strip())
print(lst)
```

Your actual issue is obviously that method parse expects a str, not a list.

Also check this: *list* is a reserved term and should not be used as variable name.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost this :) Adding "s = '\n'.join(lst)" to your code make it work in this context. The parser requires a string with "\n"  at the end of the line. Thx about "list" warning :)

Answer (score 0):

The parser() requires a string containing a list of lines finishing by "\n".

Here is the code working:

```
import re
import robotexclusionrulesparser as rerp
p = rerp.RobotExclusionRulesParser()
lst = []

with open('robots.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
            lst.append(line.strip())

s = '\n'.join(lst)
p.parse(s)
print(p)
```